# Enlarge checkbox clicking area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table column (`td`) with checkboxes in it. How can I make clicking on an empty space inside `td` to check\uncheck checkbox?

I can use only that td, can't set event handlers to the `tr`, or other `td`s. Also I need empty space only in that `td` to act this way.

[checkboxes column http://dl.dropbox.com/u/347209/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-12%20at%205.54.33%20PM.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/347209/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-12%20at%205.54.33%20PM.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your checkbox into a `<label>` - have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/RThrM/

Comment: This way I need to remove all padding from that `td`, kinda don't want to mess with html and css in this case. Is there a js way?

Comment: This is how you should always do it. The <p> tags aren't necessary though (and also invalid). I suggest `<label>

    <input type="checkbox" />

</label>​`

Comment: I added `<p>` tags to quickly expand the visual dimensions of `<label>`, naturally one will use some different way to lay out the contents. And Oded's solution seems best given the OP's clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Attach an `OnClick` event handler to the `TR` that will toggle the checkbox that is on that `TR`.

See [Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) and [Attaching Event Handlers in Javascript](http://javascript.about.com/library/blseparate.htm).

If you are using jQuery, look at the [Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) documentation.

Comment: Can't do that because all other `td`'s have another on click event on it

Comment: @maxt3r - That's one of those tiny details you could have shared in your question. Why can't you use these existing event handlers then?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I need only click on empty space in that `td` to do that.